# Xamarin.Forms - doesn't match event type bug in clicked event

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i don't know what is the problem here it works properly before the update, it started after i update xamarin to the latest version few days ago and all of my clicked event in xaml became like this in the image

[image: Clicked Event in xaml]

even i have the matching names for the event in xaml and the codebehind C#
i kept getting this error

**.xaml**

```
<Button Text="Place Orders" x:Name="btnPlaceorder" TextColor="White" Style="{StaticResource BtnPrincipale}" FontAttributes="Bold" Clicked="btnPlaceorder_Clicked"  BackgroundColor="Orange"/>
```

**.cs**

```
private async Task btnPlaceorder_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Comment: it is not recognising the `Task` for the event handler. It is probably expecting `void`

Comment: Event handlers should have void return types

Comment: @Nkosi but it works before i don't event change it to anything, it just became like that suddenly

Comment: @Jason should i remove the async?

Comment: the async should not matter, the problem is the return type

Comment: @Jason it works now thank you

Comment: @Jeremy thanks for asking this question as i did the same as you and updated just before i went away for 3 weeks and then came back to loads of errors i was pulling my hair out :( i even rolled back and started working on an old project, but now its all working thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clicked event is expecting return

```
private async void btnPlaceorder_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
```